# Maven, m2e, not building local dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

We have a setup of Maven module like this:

- Parent

  - common
  - webapp

Where webapp has declared a dependency to common.

In our Eclipse environment, using m2e, we made a change in `common`. Then ran maven package on `webapp`, deployed and tested the webservice. There was now a fault that indicated that the package we had done did not include the latest changes in common.

We are trying to figure out the best way to use Maven in our day-to-day development. So whats the best practice to handle situations like this?

The way to solve this issue would have been to; Make changes in `common`, save them, run maven install, make changes in `webapp`, run maven package, and use the war file for tests. But this contains a lot manual steps.

I guess another way would be to run maven package on the parent, but as the parent grows with more modules this will take longer.

Comment: Are the projects part of the same multi-modules project? If so, you should not run Maven from a module but from the parent.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, they both share the same parent. But if the parent would grow from just containing two module, the build would take a very long time just for changes to two modules, would it not?

Comment: It would but then the question becomes: if only those two projects are ever changing, why are there other modules to begin with? They could be independant projects.

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect changes to common to be available unless you package and deploy it separately?  Maven is not magic and it cannot make magic things happen.  The solution in this case is to either manually deploy common or do as you suggest package and deploy the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent  1.0-SNAPSHOT
        +common 1.0-SNAPSHOT
         +webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

1. You must use a snapshot version in the parent and reuse the same version in both module.
2. You must import every module in eclipse
3. You must run mvn clean install from the parent

If you do all this, Eclipse will recognize when there's a dependency 'webapp' project to 'common' project. Eclipse takes the 'common' project in the build-path of the 'webapp' project. Any change in 'common' is seen by 'webapp'.